# Auto mirroring in jetpack compose Icons

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using jetpack compose now, and my app has two locales which one of them is RTL, and the other one is LTR.
Everything works fine when the user changes the locale, the whole layout will be rearranged.

The only problem I have is the mirroring of Jetpack Compose Icons.
I have an IconButton like this:

```
IconButton(onClick = { backView(true) }) {
    Icon(Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "back")
}
```

Which is used to navigate back.
My problem is this Icon won't be mirrored when the user switches to RTL Locale.

Before Compose, I imported the `arrow_back` vector, and it has a checkbox for `auto mirroring` for RTL support.

How can I achieve the RTL support in Compose?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use `scale` to mirror the icon:

```
IconButton(onClick = { backView(true) }) {
    Icon(modifier = Modifier.scale(scaleX = -1f, scaleY = 1f), 
    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "back")
}
```

If you want to do this throughout your app, you could just create a Modifier extension function. Here we'll call it `mirror`:

```
@Stable
fun Modifier.mirror(): Modifier {
    return if (Locale.getDefault().layoutDirection == LayoutDirection.RTL)
        this.scale(scaleX = -1f, scaleY = 1f)
    else
        this
}
```

And then apply it:

```
IconButton(onClick = { backView(true) }) {
    Icon(modifier = Modifier.mirror(), 
    imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "back")
}
```

See [Scale](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/Modifier#(androidx.compose.ui.Modifier).scale(kotlin.Float,kotlin.Float))

Comment: I was about to mention this, but you see sir this would not work for icons that do not have vertical symmetry, since rotation would make them look like they're upside down. It works for the arrow though, but the question should appeal for a more universal answer.

Comment: I updated my solution. Use scale with the scaleX parameter set to -1. Scale with negative values produces mirroring.

Comment: Yeah that oughta do it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. this approach works fine, but I need to check the locale everywhere I use Icons. ( while in the usual way, I mean when not to use Compose, you don't need to). is there any way that the procedure of mirroring be automatically and based on the locale? ( just like when you check the "support RTL" check box while you're adding a new vector") @Johann

Comment: @Mohammad I updated my response. Just use a custom modifier that applies scaling if RTL is enabled.

Comment: I think it's better to use `LocalLayoutDirection` in composables.

Comment: Update: this was fixed and release on 1.2.0-alpha06: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-foundation#1.2.0-alpha06 . You'll also need to add `android:autoMirrored="true"` inside your vector file.

Answer (score 9):

*NOTE: this answer is based on @Johann answer. but this answer works better in newer compose versions.*

- Create a Modifier extension.

  ```
  @Stable
  fun Modifier.mirror(): Modifier = composed {
      if (LocalLayoutDirection.current == LayoutDirection.Rtl)
          this.scale(scaleX = -1f, scaleY = 1f)
      else
          this
  }
  ```
- Then use the `mirror()` where you need.

  ```
  Icon(
      imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack,
      contentDescription = null,
      modifier = Modifier.mirror()
  )
  ```

Answer (score 1):

This won't mirror the icon but works:
I added the extended material icons dependency and used the `ArrowForward` instead of `ArrowBack`

```
implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

With compose version 1.2.0 out all you need to do is to add autoMirrored attribute to your vector drawable.:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:autoMirrored="true"
    android:viewportWidth="24"
    android:viewportHeight="24">
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `implementation("androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.6.0-beta01")` and use:

```
Icons.AutoMirrored.Filled.ArrowBack
```

And this will mirror the arrow back icon in RTL. Have a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-material#1.6.0-alpha05) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `graphicsLayer` modifier:

```
IconButton(onClick = { backView(true) }) {
    Icon(
        imageVector = Icons.Filled.ArrowBack, 
        contentDescription = "back",
        modifier = Modifier.graphicsLayer { rotationY = 180f }
    )
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

This is updated version of the modifier

```
@Stable
fun Modifier.mirror(): Modifier = composed {
   if (LocalLayoutDirection.current.ordinal == LayoutDirection.RTL)
      this.scale(scaleX = -1f, scaleY = 1f)
   else
     this
}
```